# can not do blackberry z10 app developement

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

For my course curriculum I need to work on blackberry mobile app development for **Blackberry Z10 mobile**.
I googled a lot and found that I need Momentics IDE, I got Momentics IDE and installed it on windows 10, but opening, it says can not connect to internet.

It could not get API levels so I am unable to make project using cascades.

The official developers page on blackberry site does not have momentics IDE.

Please tell me which IDE can I use to make apps for **Blackberry Z10 mobile**, or how to get SDKs for momentics IDE.

If somebody have developement IDEs, SDKs etc please share with me.

I know it is outdated but I need it. Please help me.

I am searching web but not getting and IDE functional IDE now in 2022. Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Infrastructure that supported BlackBerry OS and BlackBerry 10 was shut down on January 4th, 2022.  This includes resources required for development. Tools for developing apps for these platforms were also removed from the BlackBerry web site. You can find the official announcement here: https://www.blackberry.com/us/en/support/devices/end-of-life

Comment: great thanks for your reply, but I got and installed momentics ide, API levels etc and now able to create a project. But now I am stuck in sideloading the project in my blackberry Z10 mobile, actually i am not able to get a bbidtoken.csk and author certificate. I just need to make and install the app for my own, in my own phone, just for learning only, and also it is unsigned app in development mode only, please tell me is there any way by which I can get blackberry id token and author certificate, or write my own id token and author.p12 files.

Comment: The BlackBerry signing authority servers that created the BB10 developer tokens and signing keys are no longer online. It is not possible to create these offline.